# Python Socket not on local network

Tags: python-3.x, client, server, wan, python-sockets

I wrote a basic server-client scripts using sockets, and everything works fine on my LAN, but it doesnt work when im trying to connect to the client thats not in my LAN. I also port forwarded these ports

this is server

```
###SERVER####


def ChatConnection():
    print('Waiting for a connection...\n')
    SOCKET = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    SOCKET.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    HOST = ''
    PORT = 8989
    SOCKET.bind((HOST, PORT))
    SOCKET.listen(1)
    CONN, ADDR = SOCKET.accept()
    print('You can now chat')
    while True:
        MSG = str(input('\n[YOU]> '))
        while not MSG: MSG = str(input('\n[YOU]> '))
        CONN.send(MSG.encode())
        print('\nAwaiting reply...')
        REPLY = CONN.recv(4096).decode()
CONN.close()
```

this is client

```
###CLIENT###



def ChatConnection():
    print('Waiting for a connection...\n')
    while True:
        try:
            HOST = SERVER EXTERNAL IP
            PORT = 8989
            SOCKET = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            SOCKET.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
            SOCKET.connect((HOST, PORT))
            print('You can now chat with server')
            print('\nWaiting for server...')
            while True:
                REPLY = SOCKET.recv(4096)
                print('\n[USER]> %s'%REPLY.decode())
                MSG = str(input('\n[YOU]> '))
                while not MSG: MSG = str(input('\n[YOU]> '))
                SOCKET.send(MSG.encode())
                print('\nAwaiting reply...')
            SOCKET.close()
    except Exception: pass
```

what i need to do so this will work on the WAN?

Comment: did you port forward on **both** sides?

Comment: thats makes so sense. i cant ask for someone to port forward, there are many ways to chat without port forward. what about all those online chats?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that port forward **WORKS**, to check this run your program and try running a port scan on your public IP.
[Port scanning tool](https://pentest-tools.com/network-vulnerability-scanning/tcp-port-scanner-online-nmap)

- Try to change the `HOST` to `0.0.0.0`.
- If that didn't work go to CMD and write `netstat -a` while your script is running.
  Search for the port you are listening on and make sure the IP is `0.0.0.0`.
- If the IP is `0.0.0.0` then try to turn off your Firewall.